# Why Prettier format removes brackets in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, prettier

I'm using Prettier to format TypeScript files and it always removes the brackets like in the scenario below:

```js
private requestFilterHooks: Dict<(...args: any[]) => (Promise<void> | void)> = {};
```

will be converted to:

```js
private requestFilterHooks: Dict<(...args: any[]) => Promise<void> | void> = {};
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks for the comments, i want define it support 2 kinds of return types

Comment: I'd suggest submitting a request to https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues

Comment: @lena https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/13955

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are removed in function types just like they're removed in similar function expressions as the precedence rules are similar for types and values:

**Prettier 2.8.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuc0DOMAEAPTBeTACgEMBKfAPiICNMBqTMUgbgB1YBPABzkwA18RYkkwBBcniqEAQpgA+mAMIsQAGhAQuMAJbpkoYgCdDEAO4AFIwjTIQxADaniHG+uqHiYANZwYAZWIAWzgAGW0oOGQAMwc0ODcPb18-Lk9wgHNkGEMAV3iQOEDqOAATEtKQ4ih0nOJ0uAAxCENA4hgdattiHJgINRAACxhA+wB1Ae14NFSwOD9rSe0AN0mOWzA0VxBwuMMYcw901ujY-IArNGw-DPs4AEUciHgT+zj1VMNd2xhuODQwQzaLT9LiA2CjbQlGADZAADgADO8THFRh4uLZQX84IYlpF1ABHR7wA6aGwoYhoAC0EVKpX6hjghO0DIOdWOSBir3ycUC2iyuW5NzgonagOoPTg5mxYQiLzeIDQQoeT0iHNO6hgxGoEKhMKQACYNR5tPYMooIIF2QU0ABWfo5OIAFS1ZM58qWeQAklByrA-ACgTBRD6-D9bnK4ABfSNAA)

**Input:**

```
const x = (a) => (b + c);
type X = (a: A) => (B | C);
```

**Output:**

```
const x = (a) => b + c;
type X = (a: A) => B | C;
```

Note that removing these parentheses doesn't change the meaning of the code.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, example provided in the example do change the meaning of the code.

Comment: @huanfeng at least not in this universe

Comment: i mean the example in question, not your example...

Comment: the example in the question, the expected requestFilterHooks define the value should always be a function, after conversion, it could be return a void, that's the difference.

Comment: @huanfeng is this trolling?